# Does UIView aniamteWithDuration exit out if property values match

Tags: ios, animation

If I wanted to animate a property value, say `alpha`, to 0, if the view's `alpha` property is already 0, does the animation still happen? Or does it exit out? I think I've read somewhere it does, but can't seem to find any documentation on that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does but you won't see it. It changes alpha from 0 to 0. After that, it executes the completion handler.

Comment: Shit, I just confirmed this as well. It does actually do the work it seems, I was hoping it would not even execute the animation block and simply move to the completion block.